# Уменьшительное от Акакий

Tags: имена-собственные

Попалась такая картинка:

[image]

А действительно, какая уменьшительная форма от имени Акакий?

Comment: Каково увеличительное от Акакия?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Акаша. Пойдёт?

Answer (score 2):

Не стал бы писать очевидную вещь, но грумант, не к ночи будь помянут, вынудил.

> Акаха, Акаша: АКАКИЙ;

Указатель производных (уменьшительных) имен
http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/info/petr/imsm/

Никаких Кис и Кок для Акакия там не значится, это уменьшительные от других имен

> Киса: НАРКИСС, НАРКИССА;  
> Кока: КОНКОРДИЙ, КОНКОРДИЯ, КОНСТАНТИН, НИКОЛАЙ;
> Кика: КИКИЛИЯ;

(там же)

Понятно, что запрета назвать человека как вздумается нет, но мы, как понимаю, о реально употребляемых ник-неймах...

Кстати, могу сразу сказать, что первый предударный слог обычно в уменьшительном имени не пропадает, особенно если ударение падает на второй. Тем более - не искажается ударный. Исключения - грузинские варианты уменьшительных имен. Там свои закономерности. Но чтоб Акакий стал Кикой - это даже им в голову не придет.

Comment: > Но чтоб Акакий стал Кикой - это даже им в голову не придет.

Никому не пришло бы в голову, что Александр - это Сашка, но для русских, как известно, невозможного нет.

Comment: Простите, но эта модель весьма продуктивна. И "Акаща" как раз по ней и сделана. Вот "Шура", "Шурик" - от Александра это действительно нечто.

Comment: Про "Шурика" забыла, спасибо, что напомнили. Но все-таки уже на уровне "Сашки" наблюдается традиция, установившаяся в рядах русского народа, уродовать имена до неузнаваемости, а потом называть их "уменьшительными".

Answer (score 1):

Акакичка, Акашук, Акашутка..